# Get the latlng of a marker on the map by tag

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a panto marker function which requires the longitude and latitude variables. I have the ability to send the contact name as a variable.

The contact name is the tag for the marker i want to pan to. Is it possible for me to get the longitude and latitude of the marker by tag?

Here is my panto function

```
 function pantoUser(lati,longi,i)
{
    jQuery("#dispatcher").gmap3({
        action: 'panTo',
        args:[new google.maps.LatLng(lati,longi)],
        zoom: 7
               });
               currentPoint = i;
                jQuery("#dispatcher").css({
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                });
                jQuery('#markerTitle' + i + '').fadeIn({
                    duration: 200,
                    queue: false
                }).animate({
                    bottom: "32px"
                }, {
                    duration: 200,
                    queue: false
                });
            jQuery("#target").stop(true, true).fadeIn(1200).delay(500).fadeOut(1200);
                jQuery("#dispatcher").css({
                    cursor: 'default'
                });
                jQuery('#markerTitle' + i + '').stop(true, true).fadeOut(2000, function() {
                    jQuery("#dispatcher").css({
                        bottom: "0"
                    })
                jQuery("#target").stop(true, true).fadeIn(1200).delay(500).fadeOut(1200);
                });
```

}

I was thinking of something like this?

```
 function locateLastSpeaker(name) {
var lati = SOMEHOW GET IT
var longi = SOMEHOW GET IT
pantoUser(lati,longi,1)
```

}

EDIT after trying duncans solution!!

```
var stuMarkers = {};

function addMarker(i, lati, longi, id, name, state, datestring) {
 var placename = name;
 stuMarkers[placename].lat = lati;
 stuMarkers[placename].lng = longi;
    $('#dispatcher').gmap3(
      { action: 'addMarker', ....etc
```

Comment: Sure, but you gotta include some code to get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an array as barry suggests, what about an object, keyed on the name.  That way you won't even have to loop.

```
var stuMarkers = {};  // global variable outside of any function

// loop creating your markers

function addMarker(i, lati, longi, id, name, state, datestring) {
 var placename = name;
 stuMarkers[placename] = {};
 stuMarkers[placename].lat = lati;
 stuMarkers[placename].lng = longi;
 stuMarkers[placename].i = i;
 ...
}


function locateLastSpeaker(name) {
  pantoUser(stuMarkers[name].lat,stuMarkers[name].lng,stuMarkers[name].i);
}
```

Comment: nice, but rather than the "= new google.maps.LatLng(x,y);" could i store the lat and long separately in the object? Then i dont have to change my PanTo function.

Comment: looks good, but i have a problem... I have done the above i have added the code around my add markers function. for some reason the "stuMarkers[placename].lat = lati;" lines stop my markers adding. Comment them out and it works again..

see my edit above

Comment: Cheers for the update, now the markers are adding but get the following: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined iframecontent.html:110
locateLastSpeaker iframecontent.html:110
stuMarkers iframecontent.html:42
b.extend.ready jquery-1.4.4.min.js:29
u

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to each marker - probably in an array.

When you want to find a particular marker, loop though that array, and find the particular marker.

Then do what you want with it.